# How to do server side pagination in .net core api using ado.net?

Tags: c#, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, server-side-rendering

I am new to ASP.Net Core and i have created API for basic CRUD operations in .Net Core. And now i have created another ASP.Net Core MVC project in which I consume this API.
I am displaying data in jquery datatable and now i want to do server-side pagination in it.
I don't know how to get current page number from jquery datatable.

**My Solution**
[Solution Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtccZ.png)

> My API Controller

```
using BookStore.Data.Interfaces;
using BookStore.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace BookStoreAPI.Controllers{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
{
    private IBookRepository bookRepository;
    public BooksController(IBookRepository repo)
    {
        bookRepository = repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks()
    {

        return bookRepository.GetAllBooks().ToList();
    }
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Book GetBookById(int id)
    {
        return bookRepository.GetBook(id);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public Book AddBook([FromBody] Book book)
    {
        return bookRepository.AddBook(book);
    }
    [HttpPut]
    public Book UpdateBook([FromForm] Book book)
    {
        return bookRepository.UpdateBook(book);
    }
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void DeleteBook(int id)
    {
        bookRepository.DeleteBook(id);
    }
    [HttpGet("GetBooksByvalue/{value}")]
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooksByvalue(string value)
    {
        return bookRepository.GetBooksByvalue(value).ToList();
    }
}}
```

> My MVC Controller

```
using BookStoreWebUI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookStoreWebUI.Controllers{
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class BooksController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();

    }
    
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetJsonBooks()
    {
        

        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books"))
            {
                var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(apiresponse);
            }
        }
        return Json(books);


    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public ViewResult GetBooks()
    {
        return View();

    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooks(int id)
    {

        Book book = new Book();
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/GetBookById/" + id))
            {
                var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(apiresponse);
            }
        }
        return View("GetBooks", book);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Getbooksbyvalue(string value)
    {
        ViewData["Getbooksby"] = value;
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/GetBooksByvalue/" + value))
            {
                var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(apiresponse);
            }
        }
        //return View("Index", books);
        return Json(books);

    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult AddBook()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> AddBook(Book book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
            {
                StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(book), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (var response = await httpclient.PostAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/", content))
                {
                    var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(apiresponse);
                }
            }
            return Json(book);
        }
        return Json("Error");
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateBook(int id)
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/" + id))
            {
                var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(apiresponse);
            }
        }
        return Json(book);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateBook(Book book)
    {
        Book recievedbook = new Book();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.Id.ToString()), "Id");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.Title), "Title");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.Author), "Author");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.PublicationYear.ToString()), "PublicationYear");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.IsAvailable.ToString()), "IsAvailable");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.CallNumber), "CallNumber");

                using (var response = await httpclient.PutAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/", content))
                {
                    var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    ViewBag.Result = "Success";
                    recievedbook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(apiresponse);
                }
            }
        }
        return Json(recievedbook);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> DeleteBook(int id)
    {
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpclient.DeleteAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/" + id))
            {
                string apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

        }
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        return Json("Success");
    }
}}
```

> My Ajax Method

```
function getallbooks(element) {
        var clickedButton = element;
        var counter = 0;
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Books/GetJsonBooks",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            data: '{}',
            async: true,
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        $("#tblbooks").DataTable(
            {
                bLengthChange: true,
                lengthMenu: [[10, 20,50, -1], [10, 20,50, "All"]],
                bFilter: true,
                bSort: true,
                //serverSide: true,
                bPaginate: true,
                bDestroy: true,
                data: response,
                columns: [
                    { "data": "id", "name": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "title", "name": "title", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "author", "title": "author", "name": "author", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "publicationYear", "name": "publicationYear", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "isAvailable", "name": "isAvailable", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "callNumber", "name": "callNumber", "autoWidth": true },
                    {
                        data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-info' onclick=EditBook('" + row.id + "'); >Edit</a>";
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteBook('" + row.id + "'); >Delete</a>";
                        }
                    }
                ]
                });
    };
```

> My Model Class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BookStoreWebUI.Models{
public class Book
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Title is Required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Author Name is Required")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Publication Year is Required and is only number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{4}$")]
    public int PublicationYear { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Check Availabilty")]
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Call Number is Required")]
    public string CallNumber { get; set; }
}}
```

> My IBookRepository interface

```
using BookStore.Data.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BookStore.Data.Interfaces{
public interface IBookRepository
{
    //IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks(int pageindex, int pagesize);
    IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks();
    IEnumerable<Book> GetBooksByvalue(string value);
    Book GetBook(int id);
    void DeleteBook(int id);

    Book AddBook(Book book);
    Book UpdateBook(Book book);

} }
```

> My BookRepository Class

```
using BookStore.Data.Interfaces;
using BookStore.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BookStore.Data.Repositories
{
public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    public string constr;
    private readonly ILogger<BookRepository> _logger;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = null;
    SqlDataReader sdr = null;

    public BookRepository(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BookRepository> logger)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        constr = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:myconnection"];
        _logger = logger;
    }

    //public IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks(int pageindex, int pagesize)
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks()
    {
        List<Book> list = new List<Book>();
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("getallbooks", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchvalue", null);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pagesize", pagesize);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageindex", pageindex);
                sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(new Book
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Id"]),
                        Title = Convert.ToString(sdr["Title"]),
                        Author = Convert.ToString(sdr["Author"]),
                        PublicationYear = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["PublicationYear"]),
                        IsAvailable = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsAvailable"]),
                        CallNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr["CallNumber"])

                    });
                }
                sdr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex,"Error at GetAllBooks() : ");
                list = null;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public Book GetBook(int id)
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("getallbooks", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchvalue", id);
                sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    book = new Book
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Id"]),
                        Title = Convert.ToString(sdr["Title"]),
                        Author = Convert.ToString(sdr["Author"]),
                        PublicationYear = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["PublicationYear"]),
                        IsAvailable = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsAvailable"]),
                        CallNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr["CallNumber"])
                    };
                }
                sdr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error at GetBookbyid() : ");
                book = null;
            }
        }
        return book;
    }



    public Book AddBook(Book book)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("addbook", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", book.Title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", book.Author);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublicationYear", book.PublicationYear);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsAvailable", book.IsAvailable);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallNumber", book.CallNumber);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error at AddBook() : ");
                book = null;
            }
        }
        return book;
    }

    public Book UpdateBook(Book book)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("updatebook", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", book.Id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", book.Title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", book.Author);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublicationYear", book.PublicationYear);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsAvailable", book.IsAvailable);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallNumber", book.CallNumber);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error at AddBook() : ");
                book = null;
            }
        }
        return book;
    }
    public void DeleteBook(int id)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("deletebook", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error at AddBook() : ");
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooksByvalue(string value)
    {
        List<Book> list = new List<Book>();
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("getbooksbyvalue", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchvalue", value);
                sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(new Book
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Id"]),
                        Title = Convert.ToString(sdr["Title"]),
                        Author = Convert.ToString(sdr["Author"]),
                        PublicationYear = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["PublicationYear"]),
                        IsAvailable = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsAvailable"]),
                        CallNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr["CallNumber"])

                    });
                }
                sdr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error at GetBooksbyvalue() : ");
                list = null;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}}
```

> My Stored Procedure

```
    USE [BooksDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getallbooks] 
  @SearchValue NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,  
  @PageNo INT = 0,
  @PageSize INT = 10,
  @SortColumn INT = 0,
  @SortDirection NVARCHAR(10) = 'ASC'

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT on;

  DECLARE @TotalCount AS INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book)

  DECLARE @FirstRec int, @LastRec int
  SET @FirstRec = @PageNo * @PageSize + 1;
  SET @LastRec = (@PageNo + 1) * @PageSize;

  SET @SearchValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchValue)) 

  ; WITH CTE_Results AS  
  (  
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 

      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 0 AND @SortDirection='asc')  
            THEN Id  
      END ASC,  
      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 0 AND @SortDirection='desc')  
          THEN Id
      END DESC, 
      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 1 AND @SortDirection='asc')  
            THEN Title 
      END ASC,  
      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 1 AND @SortDirection='desc')  
            THEN Title 
      END DESC,  
      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 2 AND @SortDirection='asc')  
            THEN Author  
      END ASC,  
      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 2 AND @SortDirection='desc')  
            THEN Author
      END DESC,
      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 3 AND @SortDirection='asc')  
            THEN CallNumber  
      END ASC,  
      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 3 AND @SortDirection='desc')  
            THEN CallNumber
      END DESC
    )
    AS RowNum,
    COUNT(*) OVER() as FilteredCount,
    Id, 
    Title, 
    Author, 
    PublicationYear,
    IsAvailable,
    CallNumber 
    FROM Book 
    
    WHERE ISNULL(@SearchValue, '') = ''
    OR Title LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%'
    OR Author LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%'
    OR PublicationYear LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%'
    OR CallNumber LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%'

  ) 

  SELECT
     Id, 
    Title, 
    Author, 
    PublicationYear,
    IsAvailable,
    CallNumber ,
    FilteredCount,
    @TotalCount AS TotalCount
  FROM CTE_Results
  WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @FirstRec AND @LastRec  

    END
```

**What i need now is to adjust this code for server-side pagination given this stored procedure**

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? How's the pagination happening as of now?

Comment: Currently i have jquery datatable in which data is loaded and it does client-side pagiantion.
But i want to do server-side pagiantion in it. How do I do it

Comment: @Hotspot Shield, Do you mean remove the client-side pagination (JQuery Datatable), and only using the server side pagination? Or you want to use client paging and server paging together? Besides, please check your stored procedure, if the search value is not null, the pagination is not working, and if the search value is null, since you didn't assign the page index and th page size, the pagination still not working, it only return the firs page data.

Comment: I have edited my stored procedure completely.
Also I want to remove client-side pagination and only use server-side pagination.
You can see the edited stored procedure.

Comment: Generally, when we achieve the pagination, first we need to get the total count, then according to the page size to get the page count and generate the paging links, after that, when click the paging links, we could according to the page number and the page size to get the data. From your store procedure, after you execute the stored procedure, you could get the TotalCount, then you can according to it to generate the page count and the page links, after that once click the page links, you could call the store procedure based on the selected page number and page size and get the data.